# How does second-order logic relate to lambda calculus?

Tags: logic, computability, lambda-calculus

How does second-order arithmetic/logic relate to lambda calculus? By lambda calculus, I mean both typed and untyped. And is there any relationship with recursive and recursively enumerable sets?

Edit: some edits.

Comment: That's a rather fuzzy question. Could you be a bit more specific about which kind of relation you're looking for? Just name-dropping a few basic computability concepts does not help much figuring out which _connection_ to second order logic you want to know about.

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: Perhaps you suggest a fusion of second-order logic and lambda calculus in a similar fashion to the study Beeson has done for first-order logic (http://www.michaelbeeson.com/research/papers/LambdaLogic.pdf for the latest version).

Answer (score 9):

The question is rather vague. However, I recall something that you may be interested in:

[System F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_F) is a typed lambda calculus that has a very interesting property:

> An arithmetic function can be represented in System F if and only if it can be proved total in *second* order Peano arithmetic.

This also means that in System F we can represent basically all total functions we can ever imagine.

There is also a weaker system called Gödel System T, for which there is a similar theorem:

> An arithmetic function can be represented in System T if and only if it can be proved total in *first* order Peano arithmetic.

System T is the [simply typed calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_typed_lambda_calculus) enriched with booleans, natural numbers and primitive recursion on them.

Also:

- All functions representable in System F and System T are total.
- This means that those systems (unlike [the untyped lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus)) are not [Turing complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness).

All this is described in detail in [Proofs and Types](http://www.paultaylor.eu/stable/Proofs+Types.html) by Jean-Yves Girard, Yves Lafont and Paul Taylor.

Comment: Is there a system which represents precisely those functions that can be proved total in ZFC?

Answer (score 1):

The obvious result that comes to mind (which talks both of second-order logic and computability) is that second-order consequence -- when defined using the natural 'full' semantics (so second-order quantifiers run over *all* subsets of the domain) -- is not recursively axiomatizable.

Otherwise it is unclear what kind of relation is being enquired about.

Comment: Edited the question. By "consequence", you mean second-order sentences?